# C# MVC - Generar Lista de preguntas dinámica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

yo tengo el siguiente codigo en la pagina

```
        <h4 class="center-align">Selecciona la Pregunta</h4>
        <div id="set1">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="imagenid" id="pulsa_imagen" hidden />
                <label class="control-label col-md-3"> Escoja la Pregunta: </label>
                <br />

                <input id="images" type="text" name="nuevousuario" style="text-transform:uppercase;" disabled />

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>@ViewData["pregunta"]</p>
                    <input id="images" type="text" name="nuevousuario1" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="validarimagen()" />

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <br />
                <a class="control-label col-md-3" onclick="UsuarioPreguntasPartial.preguntas1()">Mostrar otra pregunta </a>

                <br />
                <input id="sigpreg" type="submit" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-default" @*onclick="UsuarioPreguntasPartial.preguntas1();"*@ />

            </div>
        </div>
```

ahora tengo una lista creada en una clase de esta forma:

public List ObtenerListado()

```
        {
            return  new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cómo se llama su caricatura favorita?",
                Value="1"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Qué color de cabello tiene su pareja?",
                Value="2"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es el nombre de su escritor favorito?",
                Value="3"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿De qué color es su cabello?",
                Value="4"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es su pelicula favorita?",
                Value="5"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es su apellido materno?",
                Value="6"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cómo se llama su artista favorito?",
                Value="7"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es el nombre de su mejor amigo/a?",
                Value="8"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es su color favorito?",
                Value="9"
            },
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text="¿Cuál es el segundo nombre de su papá?",
                Value="10"
            },

        };                        
    }
```

Lo que trato de hacer es que en esta linea se visualice una pregunta
 
[image: imagen preguntas]

yo puse este controlador, extrae las 10 preguntas y todo pero no logro que pase a esa caja de texto
 public ActionResult Index()

```
    {
        //  ViewBag.MiListado = ObtenerListado();
        PreguntaSeguridadDto val = new PreguntaSeguridadDto();
        ViewBag.MiListado = val.ObtenerListado();
        //return Json();
        ViewData["pregunta"] = val.ObtenerListado();
        //val.ObtenerListado();

        //val = val.ObtenerListado();
        return View(ViewBag.MiListado);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que no usas un DropDownListFor para selecciona la pregunta y la respuesta en un input, así con sus id puedes obtener sus valores si usaras ajax o si usaras un form Post necesitaras un modelo para poder obtener los datos.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Pregunda, new SelectList(ViewBag.MiListado,"Value","Text"), new{id="pregunta", @class="tu clase"})

@Html.TexboxFor(x=>x.Respuesta, new {id="respuesta", @class="tu clase", placeholder = "Tu pregunta"}})
```

También puedes usar un `@foerach(){<etiquetas html>}`, razor permite añadir codigo c# en las vistas

Comment: justo en esta linea @Html.TexboxFor(x=>x.Respuesta, new {id="respuesta", @class="tu clase"}) es que debe previsualizarse una pregunta random, y al hacer clic en ese texbox simplemente digito la respuesta

Comment: Eso se logra con la etiqueta placeholder, así cuando el usuario escriba todo se coloca en blanco @Html.TexboxFor(x=>x.Respuesta, new {id="respuesta", @class="tu clase", placeholder = "Tu pregunta"})

Comment: oka manuel pero esa etiqueta placeholder me permite que aparezca cualquier pregunta, cabe recordar que yo las almaceno en una clase

Comment: Que es lo que necesitas exactamente ?

Comment: que en el input pueda aparecer la pregunta aleatoria guardada en la clase ObtenerListado()

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa es un listado y otra un texto simple.

Si vas a mostrar una pregunta random debes obtener del listado esa pregunta

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PreguntaSeguridadDto val = new PreguntaSeguridadDto();
    var listado = val.ObtenerListado();

    var rnd = Random();
    var index = rnd.Next(0, listado.Length);

    ViewBag.MiListado = listado;
    ViewBag.pregunta = listado[index];

    return View();
}
```

usando la clase `Random` obtienes un index de la pregunta d ela lista

[Random.Next(Int32, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.5#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Para ver esto en la view usarias

```
<p>@ViewData.pregunta</p>
```

O si lo quieres editar seria

```
<input type="text" name="pregunta" value="@ViewData.pregunta">
```

Comment: Error CS1061 "List<SelectListItem>" no contiene una definición para "length" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión "length" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List<SelectListItem>" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?) MiSegundaAplicacionMVC C:\Users\agarcia\source\repos\MiSegundaAplicacionMVC\MiSegundaAplicacionMVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs 19 Activo
 me salio un error como esto,